# Regex needed for search and replace please

Tags: regex, replace

I need a regex that will find all strings like the ones below, replace the [path] with my own, and remove the –[guid] from the filename (or 33 characters preceding ".png)")

Format: **url(/[path]/[filename]-[guid].png)**

Example:

```
url(/assets/application/facebook-button-dc8bbeecddef2c5cb3fb74e01177a632.png)
url(/assets/chart/tooltip/arrow-875223c23a34df0bdbc4a500b5dfb5f6.png)
```

and replace it  with:

Format: **url(/Images/Finesse/[source filename].png)**

```
url(/Images/Finesse/facebook-button.png
url(/Images/Finesse/arrow.png)
```

Dashes within the filename should not be removed.  We can assume every desired string will begin with "url(/assets/" and end with ".png)"  We cannot assume that ".png)" will be the end of line, nor can we assume "url" will be the beginning of line.

The expression will be used in VS2012 if that matters.

Thank you

EDIT-----

Sorry, I had something like this

```
^(url\(/assets)+.+(\.png\))$
```

or something like this

```
^(url\(/assets)+.+(-)+.+(\.png\))$
```

started to find the string...which it kinda does.  I guess the question should have been about how to select a specific number of characters in front of the .png and maybe something about substitution.  Thanks for taking some time to comment.

Comment: what have you tried so far? i'm sure someone could help find problems in an existing regex, but SO is not a "free code" site. you've got to show some effort to get help.

Comment: ^^ What they said.  Also, I'm guessing your first Formatted output is missing the `)`

Comment: I should have added that I'm not 'that guy' but I thought I'd keep it mature and not ruin the question.  I usually do my own research but this is just a one-time run so I thought SO could help me out (like it used to be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s@^/([^/]+/)+(.+)-[^-]+(\.[^.]+)\)$@/Images/Finesse/$2$3)@
```

Please mail my check to my P.O. box at your earliest convience. I shouldn't have done this, you  should learn to regex yourself it is a incredible tool and extremely powerful in capable hands, but I can't help but solve a fun problem!

http://www.myregextester.com/?r=1c59cda1

Comment: yep, thanks, fun wasn't it, that's the spirit.  More importantly, thanks for  the site link...I was using regexpal.com so this one is much more useful.